# Inner class string passed to LWC being cut off

Tags: lightning-web-components, string, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a custom lwc development that gets a configuration object from the backend via `@wire` decorator that is cutting off one of the response properties.

```
{
  "cascadeMode": true,
  "frame": "current frame",
  "label": "OpenAI",
  "mappings": {
    "standard": {
      "method": "POST",
      "requestJSON": "{\r\n  \"model\": \"model\",\r\n  \"messages\": \"lwc_messages#_append[{'content':'lwc_content','role':'user'}#_atfirst_{'content':'lwc_frame','role':'system'}]\",\r\n  \"temperature\": 1,\r\n  \"top_p\": 1,\r\n  \"n\": 1,\r\n  \"stream\": false,\r\n  \"max_tokens\": 250,\r\n  \"pr",
      "type": "standard"
    }
  }
}
```

But my `requestJSON` property is way longer and looks like this:

```
{
    "model": "model",
    "messages": "lwc_messages@_append[{'content':'lwc_content','role':'user'}@_atfirst_{'content':'lwc_frame','role':'system'}]",
    "temperature": 1,
    "top_p": 1,
    "n": 1,
    "stream": false,
    "max_tokens": 250,
    "presence_penalty": 0,
    "frequency_penalty": 0
}
```

I've tried doing my backend call from the `connectedCallback` instead of using a `@wire` but no luck.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Regards,

Comment: Please [edit] to add the code snippet showing how this response gets populated. We have APIs that return far more data than this, so it's not a fundamental limitation.

Comment: @PhilW I'm just adding the value (which is stored on a LongTextArea field in a CustomMetadata record) to an `@AuraEnabled` string property

Comment: OK, so I'm guessing you are getting the LongTextArea field value from a Custom Metadata Type record after getting that record through `getInstance`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm#apex_System_CustomMetadataType_getinstance_devName); to get more than the first 255 characters, you have to explicitly query (SOQL) the CMT record.

Comment: @PhilW, this is a brilliant idea! I think you should post this as an answer for later readers, even if the OP seems to have lost interest.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you are getting the LongTextArea field value from a Custom Metadata Type record after getting that record through `getInstance`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm#apex_System_CustomMetadataType_getinstance_devName); to get more than the first 255 characters, you have to explicitly query (SOQL) the CMT record.

Our approach is to use `getInstance` and only follow this using an SOQL query if the returned long text area field value is 255 characters long.

There is a chance that the full value is exactly 255 characters long and in this case the query is unnecessary, but most of the time the values are either less than 255 in length (so no query) or more than 255 (so must be queried to get the whole value).